# Getting strange "undefined" value on the output of Closure function

Tags: javascript, function, loops

Friends!

Anyone can tell me, why my function below give me an extra value "undefined" on the end of the output string.

I think, probably mistake in my not so clear knowledges about closers functions. ^)

Thanks in advance to all.

```
function makeBuffer() {
    var butterStin = ''; //local variable for storage buffer data

    return function buffer(value) {
        return butterStin += String(value);
    };

}

var buffer = makeBuffer();

buffer('Closures');
buffer(' Must');
buffer(' Use!');

console.log( buffer() ); // Closures Must Use!
```

Current result on the output: "Closures Must Use!undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the following line:

```
console.log( buffer() );
```

Is calling the buffer function without an argument, so `value` is undefined.

You could change the buffer function if neccessary:

```
return function buffer(value) {
    return typeof value === "undefined" ?  bufferStin : butterStin += String(value);
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Also we can choose condition if (arguments.length == 0)